# Cannot call a simple function in scilab?

Tags: scilab

lets say I have written a function for adding two numbers.

```
function [result] = add_twonum(a1,a2)

result = a1+a2;

endfunction
```

in the main file, when I call

```
result = add_twonum(1,2)
```

I expect result = 3 .

However it says

`!--error 4`

Undefined variable: `add_twonum`

Please help me. I have used `Matlab` a lot but never `scilab`. I tried every possible way I know of. like changing current directory etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main file, you need to execute the function first, with

```
exec('add_twonum.sci');
```

assuming `add_twonum.sci` is the file which contains your function. Then you can call the function:

```
result = add_twonum(a1,a2);
```

Comment: You can also put your `function ... endfunction` statement at the beginning of your main file, before calling the function (it is a sort of "inline" definition).