# Call a scilab function

Tags: scilab

I'm using scilab on cloud

```
function c = example(a,b)
    c = a*b
endfunction
```

How can I call it?
I tried `exec(example(3,2))` without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868643/cannot-call-a-simple-function-in-scilab) seems to work although obviously in this case I can't call the file before calling the function.

```
result = example(3, 2)
```